# x86 assembly: Explaining disassembled code

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

Can anyone explain me following asm code please? What it does?
I already commented it a bit out..
EDIT: C++, compiled with MS Visual C++ 2008 Express Eddition -> reassembled

```
.text:39552AF5    pop     ecx
.text:39552AF6    push    eax             ; void *
.text:39552AF7    lea     eax, [ebp+procedureVariable_C] ; get a proc variable from stack to eax?
.text:39552AFA    call    sub_39501565 ; call procedure with arguments: eax(void) and the lea result?
.text:39552AFF    mov     ecx, dword_395D0A44 ; dword_395D0A44("official") char gets moved into ecx
.text:39552B05    mov     eax, ebx ; ?
.text:39552B07    call    sub_39572981 ; ? no arguments?
```

```
.text:39501565 ; int __stdcall sub_39501565(void *)  
.text:39501565 sub_39501565    proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_39501423+1Cp  
.text:39501565                                         ; sub_39501803+1Cp ...  
.text:39501565  
.text:39501565 arg_0           = dword ptr  4  
.text:39501565  
.text:39501565                 cmp     [esp+arg_0], 0  
.text:3950156A                 push    edi  
.text:3950156B                 mov     edi, eax  
.text:3950156D                 jnz     short loc_39501573  
.text:3950156F                 xor     eax, eax  
.text:39501571                 jmp     short loc_39501583  
.text:39501573 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
.text:39501573   
.text:39501573 loc_39501573:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_39501565+8j  
.text:39501573                 mov     eax, [esp+4+arg_0]  
.text:39501577                 lea     edx, [eax+1]  
.text:3950157A  
.text:3950157A loc_3950157A:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_39501565+1Aj  
.text:3950157A                 mov     cl, [eax]  
.text:3950157C                 inc     eax  
.text:3950157D                 test    cl, cl  
.text:3950157F                 jnz     short loc_3950157A  
.text:39501581                 sub     eax, edx  
.text:39501583  
.text:39501583 loc_39501583:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_39501565+Cj  
.text:39501583                 push    eax             ; int  
.text:39501584                 push    [esp+8+arg_0]   ; void *  
.text:39501588                 call    sub_39501524  
.text:3950158D                 mov     eax, edi  
.text:3950158F                 pop     edi  
.text:39501590                 retn    4  
.text:39501590 sub_39501565    endp
```

Comment: I suspect that this code uses a calling convention that uses `EAX` and `ECX` as arguments. Like Borland's fastcall/register convention. But without the content of the functions you're calling this is difficult to say. And if your program uses some kind of whole-program-optimization these might not even be conventional calling conventions.

Comment: Add the code for the functions you're calling.

Comment: way too big and complex, it's a really big disassembled DLL. I would like to see general info about the commands..?

Comment: I want to see enough of those functions to deduce which calling convention they use. And what compiler was used to compile that project?

Comment: C++, compiled with MS Visual C++ 2008 Express Eddition -> reassembled

Comment: @CodeInChaos The calling convention is "stdcall" as it says in the question's code comments, see Wikipedia x86 calling conventions for more info on stdcall.

Comment: @SoapBox: `stdcall` doesn't take an arg in EAX, so the `lea eax, ....` right before `call` would only make sense if this was actually hand-written asm or GCC `__attribute__((regparm(1)))` since it appears a second arg was passed on the stack, not ECX or EDX like Borland or Watcom regcall would (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Borland_register), or like GCC `regparm(3)`.  AFAIK, MSVC doesn't have a calling convention that passes 1 arg in EAX and the rest on the stack, and __stdcall doesn't use any register args.

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
.text:39501573
.text:39501573 loc_39501573: ; CODE XREF: sub_39501565+8j
.text:39501573 mov eax, [esp+4+arg_0]
.text:39501577 lea edx, [eax+1]
.text:3950157A
.text:3950157A loc_3950157A: ; CODE XREF: sub_39501565+1Aj
.text:3950157A mov cl, [eax]
.text:3950157C inc eax
.text:3950157D test cl, cl
.text:3950157F jnz short loc_3950157A
.text:39501581 sub eax, edx
```

looks like it is scanning for a nul byte and computing `end - start + 1`, where `start + 1`comes from `edx`.

This is what `strlen` would do!

Is there some magic here?!

Answer (score 0):

lea does not dereference anything. It just does arithmetic with the registers in its second parameter and stores the result in the first parameter.

```
lea     eax, [ebp+procedureVariable_C];
```

Assuming that `procedureVariable_C` is a constant offset it adds that offset to calculate the pointer to the corresponding variable.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to know from SO that you don't already know?  It's a couple function calls. The first passes a local parameter by reference in EAX, the second gets EAX as a parameter, perhaps a result from the first call, or perhaps just what was passed into this block in EBX.

We don't know what calling conventions are used, whether this assembler is disassembled compiler output or 'human' coding, no context, no clue to what the functions do or return. We're not exactly in a good position to help.

There is nothing unusual about this code. What's the problem?

Rgds,
Martin